# Decimal number coloring give unwanted space in lstlisting

Tags: listings, color

I'm trying to set coloring for decimal numbers in lstlisting. Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{codeblue}{rgb}{0,0,1}
\lstset{
  literate=
    {1}{{\color{codeblue}1}}{1}
    {2}{{\color{codeblue}2}}{1}
    {3}{{\color{codeblue}3}}{1}
    {4}{{\color{codeblue}4}}{1}
    {5}{{\color{codeblue}5}}{1}
    {.3}{{\color{codeblue}.3}}{2}
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{lstlisting}
    12.345
  \end{lstlisting} 
\end{document}
```

And there is show unwanted spaces before and after ".3". Any good idea?
(If I transform it to lstinline, then it seems to be ok.)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct the last line in your `\lstset` definition like this:

```
{.3}{{\color{codeblue}.3}}{1}
```

[image]

But the spacing then will be not consistent, so, I suggest another workaround:

```
{.}{{\color{codeblue}.}}{1}
```

Now this will produce:

[image]